# Convert Oracle PL/SQL code to C#

Tags: c#, encryption, plsql, des

Can someone guide me how to convert following Oracle PL/SQL code to C#, please?

```
declare 
   l_encrypted raw (100);
   p_key raw (100);
   p_plain raw(100);
   l_mode number; 
begin
  l_mode := dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_DES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC + dbms_crypto.PAD_PKCS5;
  p_key := 'A217B5BEF1477D1A';
  p_plain := '07253075';
  l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(p_plain, 'AL32UTF8'), l_mode, p_key);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_encrypted);
     --outputs this value: E4624E16DB69451A14BE265CDCC5B0AB
end;
```

My C# code is:

```
        byte[] value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("07253075");
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A217B5BEF1477D1A");
        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        };
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(value, 0, value.Length);
        cryptoStream.Close();
        Byte[] encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(string.Empty, Array.ConvertAll(encrypted, b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

However, it throws CryptographicException complaining of key size. I searched Internet and found out that key size for DES is 8 bytes, but how Oracle encrypted my text? And how can I change my code to get the same output as Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

DES traditionally accepts a 64 bit key where only 56 bits are used to encrypt the message. You could try setting the KeySize property of the DESCryptoServiceProvider to 128 and see how it goes.

Are you sure the whole key is used? the [doco](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm) for this states:

> ENCRYPT_DES
>   Data Encryption Standard. Block cipher. Uses key length of 56 bits.

I would assume that only the first 56 bits of the key are used (the first 7 characters). You could try running the encryption method in oracle with the first 7 characters and see if the output is the same compared to all 16.

If that's the case and you really want/need to to use 128 bit keys, you should move up to triple-DES or AES.

Comment: It does not allow me to encrypt with less than 15 characters, complaining Key length too short. I think as it is raw, Oracle converts it to bytes 2 characters per byte.

Comment: Have a look at **[this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_obtoo2.htm)**: _If the key length is missing or is less than 8 bytes, then the procedure raises the error ORA-28234 "Key length too short." Note that if larger keys are used, extra bytes are ignored. So a 9-byte key will not generate an exception._

Comment: Also what is the encoding used for the key string in oracle that you assign to the raw?